# After switching mouse buttons is with xinput, each computer restart resets the settings

Tags: command-line, mouse, touchpad, restart, startup-applications

How does one go about "saving" settings in Ubuntu? I change my buttons on my trackpad using `xinput set-button-map 11 3 2 1` (I'm a lefty) and it works during that session. However, when I reboot my computer, I lose my setting change, and the mouse goes back to being right-handed.

How can I get the setting to "stick" indefinitely?

Thank you!

My Machine is:

Toshiba Satellite S50-B
64-bit
Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work to make it stick *after log in*:

Add the following command to startup Applications:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xinput set-button-map 11 3 2 1"
```

Open Dash > Startup Applications > Add, then add the command above.

#### Explanation

Adding a command to Startup Applications makes the command run on *log in*, so this will work from the moment you are logged in.

The `sleep 15` is to make sure the desktop is fully loaded before the command runs. If you leave it out, the command either breaks, misses target or is overruled by possible local procedures, setting other values. This goes specifically for mouse, keyboard and screen (`xrandr`) related commands.

Comment: Hi @JacobVlijm , do the startup applications run serially? In that case the wouldn't the sleep command delay every process?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the line you want executed automatically to your `.bashrc` file.  This script is run every time you turn your computer on and every time you open a new terminal window.

1. open the file in a text editor `gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. scroll to the very bottom of the file and type your command in
   `xinput set-button-map 11 3 2 1`
3. save the file and you're done.

Comment: I don't think `.bashrc`is run on system startup, but `.profile` is - that would be a better choice IMHO